# jfienstein10 slidingmenu : Adding dynamic content whenever user opens the menu

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I have implemented the SlidingMenu successfully. 
What my requirement is that I have a menu in the form of listview .
Now few of the list items have one more component (e.g. status) which needs to be updated dynamically everytime the user opens the menu. 
I'm not able to achieve this.
Please help me .

Comment: your question is not clear , put your works here and explain in which part you have problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the method which is called when the slider is opened. There you have to add the code to update your list data.

Comment: Thanks for you response . But which method are you talking about ? I don't want to change the library source code.

Comment: You need to use this isMenuShowing() to check if the slider is opened or not. You do like this :
'if(isMenuShowing()) {
    // statement you want to perform 
} '

Comment: I've solve the issue myself. I got the reference of the listview in my parent activity and refreshed the adapter.